# Google Cloud Storage Hide/Modify Access Deny page

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When visitor access to directories, I dont want the page to show XML error message.

See below:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object cdn.example.com/avatars.
</Details>
</Error>
```

I wonder if I can hide/modify the error page via gsutil or google console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCS's support for web pages is pretty basic. You can set a custom home page, and you can set a custom 404 page, but that's it.

If you really need to handle a user browsing to a subdirectory by hand, you could perhaps create custom HTML files named, for instance, "avatars" and "avatars/". That might be a pain to maintain, but it'd probably work.